# Unable to use beeline -f filename

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am unable to run

```
beeline -f file_queries.hql

Error:
$ beeline -f edip_validations_hql.hql
beeline> {My Query}
No current connection
```

Note: I am on Kerberos so I have done kinit. Usually for beeline to work I have to do a

```
 !connect jdbc:hive2://XX.xxxx.xx.org:10000/default;principal=hive/somedomain.org@MYXXX-DEV.XX.ORG
```

However I am not clear how this would work. Any pointers would help.

Comment: this worked on EMR:

`beeline -u jdbc:hive2://hadoop@localhost:10000 -f query.sql`

Answer (score 12):

All -

I found out how to do this.

```
 beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://server.domain.<>.com:10000/default;principal=hive/server.domain.com@SERVER.DOMAIN.COM' -f filename.hql
```

Answer (score 5):

I just found out one way to run File in Hive Beeline.

Just Go to the Hive beeline

```
//use !run to run script File
beeline> !run ///C:/ScriptFile
```

Above Method surely helpful to run file beeline after connect to the hive server.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add that connect string to your .hql file prior to the query.  But I have not seen a way to pass a keytab in the connect string and that generic hive principal will ask for a user/password.  For now, I'm still using hive -f which works with my existing kinit.  Hope you find another solution since for now beeline -f is useless to me on a secure cluster.